# New java time zone info file is not supporting AEST/AEDT

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, zoneinfo

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzdata-versions-138805.html

In above link of Oracle website they say that From version tzdata2014f, Java is supporting AEST/AEDT instead of EST for Australian timezone but I have current tzdata2014i version still it is not displaying  EST only. Did I miss anything or is there anything do I need to do?

Here is small sample program I used ,

```
  import java.util.*;

public class TZ {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

 System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.home"));
  for (String id : TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()) {
   if (!id.startsWith("Australia/")) continue;
   TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(id);
   System.out.println(id + ": " + "Daylight: False : " + tz.getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT) + "/" + " Daylight: True : "+ tz.getDisplayName(true, TimeZone.SHORT));
  }
 }
}
```

And here is my time zone datafile version

C:>java -jar tzupdater.jar -V
tzupdater version 1.4.9-b01
JRE time zone data version: tzdata2014i
Embedded time zone data version: tzdata2014i

Thanks in advance for any help.

Regards,
BennY

Answer (score 1):

Your Question answers itself. As of tzdata2014f *and later* the `A` will be included:

> Australian eastern time zone abbreviations are now AEST/AEDT not EST, and similarly for the other Australian zones. That is, for eastern standard and daylight saving time the abbreviations are AEST and AEDT instead of the former EST for both; similarly, ACST/ACDT, ACWST/ACWDT, and AWST/AWDT are now used instead of the former CST, CWST, and WST.
>
> This change does not affect UTC offsets, only time zone abbreviations.

You say you are using tzdata2014i, which comes after tzdata2014f. So why are you confused about no longer seeing `EST`?

## Time zone names

By the way, you should not be using these 3-4 letter abbreviations. They are not true time zones, not standardized, and not unique (as seen here with `EST` collision).

Instead use [proper IANA time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in the format of `continent/region`. For example, [`Australia/Sydney`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australia/Sydney).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Australia/Sydney" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( zoneId );
```

> instant.toString(): 2016-09-29T22:42:40.063Z
>
> now.toString(): 2016-09-30T08:42:40.063+10:00[Australia/Sydney]

FYI, Wikipedia has a page about [Time in Australia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Australia).